# Loop a function until all elements in a python list have a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to loop a function until all elements in my list have a specific value but I have no idea how to achieve this outcome.

basically, I'm creating a list based on an API call and I need to check if all elements have "success", if not I want to run the function again until I have all elements with success status and continue my script.

list example:

```
list = ['init', 'init', 'success'] - need to repeat the function
list = ['init', 'success', 'success'] - need to repeat the function
list = ['success', 'success', 'success'] - Ready to go! continue the script
```

basically, I'm struggling with the loop and then calling the function.

Can anyone help me with that?

Cheers.

Comment: Try: `while any(word != 'success' for word in mylist):`. (Here using variable name `mylist` - use of the name `list` is not recommended because it is used for a builtin.)  Or equivalently: `while not all(word == 'success' for word in mylist):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
results = ("", "", "")
while result != ("success", "success", "success"):
   results = function(x)
```

Assuming that function returns a tuple with three *status*.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use a while loop until the function returns the desired result.

```py
myList = ['init']
while any(it != 'success' for it in myList):
    my_list = functionCall()
```

Answer (score 1):

Great, thanks for the tip about any() method. that was exactly what I need!

```
check_list = []
for a in sa_response_json['items']:
    check_list.append(a['status']['state'])

print(f"-------------------- {check_list}")

if any(it != 'success' for it in check_list):
    print("Checking devices status = Success. It can take some time")
    sleep(10)
    print("Checking again")
    check_agent_state()
else:
    print("-------------------- All devices have been onboarded")
    print(f"-------------------- {check_list}")
```